# dotenv is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dotenv

I am having a bit of trouble with the dotenv module. Within my project, I am utilizing an API which requires a API key. Thus, upon utilizing :
`require('dotenv').config()` at the top of my file and requesting `const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY` to grab the value from my .env file, I continuously get an "undefined" value when I console.log my environment variable. So far, here are my leads:

[image: This is the file structure for my project]

- I have tried hard coding the relative path to my .env file using  `require('dotenv').config(path:'./../../.env')` which did not work for me
- the dependency "dotenv" is installed properly
- I have checked my API to make sure I copied it correctly
- when I  `console.log(require('dotenv').config())`, I get an error message env variable stating that "fs.readFileSync is not a function"; I have absolutely no clue what this means... every google search I have done on this error has made me more confused

For reference here is the code I am trying to reference the .env variable in:

overview.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './overview.css';
import { RecentSearches } from '../Recent Searches/recentSearches';
import { Hourly } from '../Hourly/hourly';
import { Fiveday } from '../5 Day Forecast/fiveday';

require('dotenv').config();
console.log(require('dotenv').config());

export function Overview() {

    // this callback function receives the searched city entered from recentSearches and applies it to fetchForecast
    const getSearch = async (searchedCity) => {
        fetchForecast(searchedCity);
    }; 

    const fetchForecast = async (city) => {
        const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;
        console.log(api_key);
        // const api_key = '2220f5a5d83243938f764759211310';
        var BASE_URL = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${api_key}&q=${city}&days=3&aqi=no&alerts=no`;
    
        const response = await fetch(BASE_URL);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

        // collects all of the current weather info for your search
        const currentTempInfo = {
            city: data.location.name, 
            state: data.location.region, 
            epochDate: data.location.localtime_epoch, 
            message: data.current.condition.text, 
            wicon: data.current.condition.icon, 
            currentTemp: data.current.temp_f,
            currentHighTemp: data.forecast.forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_f,
            currentLowTemp: data.forecast.forecastday[0].day.mintemp_f,
            feelsLike: data.current.feelslike_f,
            humidity: data.current.humidity,
            rainLevel: data.current.precip_in,
            // hourlyTemps is an array, starts from midnight(index 0) and goes every hour until 11 pm(index 23)
            hourlyTemps: data.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.map((entry) => {
                let epochTime, temp;
                [epochTime, temp] = [entry.time_epoch, entry.temp_f];
                return [epochTime, temp];
            })
        };

        // console.log(currentTempInfo);
    
        const daycardInfo = [];
        // this for loop triggers and creates an array with all necessary values for the 
        function daycardForLoop() {
            for (let x=0; x < 3; x++) {
                const fcDayDates = data.forecast.forecastday[x].date_epoch;
                const dayInfo = data.forecast.forecastday[x].day; 
                const dayValues = {
                    dates: fcDayDates, 
                    message: dayInfo.condition.text, 
                    wicon: dayInfo.condition.icon, 
                    maxTemp: dayInfo.maxtemp_f, 
                    minTemp: dayInfo.mintemp_f, 
                    avgTemp: dayInfo.avgtemp_f
                };
                // pushes dayValues object into daycardInfor array
                daycardInfo.push(dayValues);
            };
        }; 
        
        daycardForLoop();
    
        // this updates the state with the forecast for the city entered
        const newData = {
            currentTempInfo: currentTempInfo,
            daycardInfo: daycardInfo
        };

        // this spits out the newly created forecast object
        return newData;
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='jumbotron' id='heading-title'>
                <h1>Welcome to <strong>Weathered</strong>!</h1>
                <h3>A Simple Weather Dashboard </h3>
            </div>

            <div className='container-fluid' id='homepage-skeleton'>
                <div className='d-flex' id='center-page'>
                    <RecentSearches getSearch={getSearch}/>
        
                    <Hourly />
                </div>
            </div>

            <Fiveday />        
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: You can't use dotenv on the client, because it has no access to environment variables (in general it's not even going to be running on the same machine where they're set) and the API it uses (fs.readFileSync) is part of Node and not available in the browser. It's unclear how your app is set up, but if you're using Webpack you could use the DefinePlugin to inject those values at build time, I wrote about this in: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Dotenv#Client-environment-variables

Comment: dotenv is a Node.js (server-side) module. You can't use it in a browser. Node has `fs` (FileSystem), a browser doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using create-react-app (CRA), you don't need dotenv.

create-react-app has a nice [guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) explaining multiples ways to use environment variables (one choice is to use a `.env` file in your root directory). The variables must start with `REACT_APP_`.

Warning: do not build your project with any secrets as environment variables (like API keys), you will also see this warning in the guide. They will be exposed to anyone accesing your React application.

Answer (score 2):

@aLittleSalty has the right answer for your case. The error you are seeing is because dotenv is supposed to be used in a node server/backend, and the browser has no access to the filesystem.

But, if you are using node for a server/backend and you stumble on this question, my answer applies to you.

The .env file path is by default `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`.
`cwd` is the current working directory: this means that dotenv looks for the file in the directory from which the code is run.

If you want to specify the relative path, this is what you should use:

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../.env')}));
```

dotenv docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-path

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `dotenv` in your `webpack` configiguration and then use `DefinePlugin` to pass the variables to your React app.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = () => {
  // Here you need to call config method of dotenv package 
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed;


  return {
    plugins: [
     new DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(env)
     })      
    ]
};
```

Comment: Is the OP using Webpack?

Comment: Yes, correct. Bundler as webpack