# dotenv in npm scripts after changing directory

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-platform, npm-scripts, dotenv

I play around with dotenv + cross-var in npm scripts. *.env* contains REPO_PULL_URL and REPO_PUSH_AUTHOR values.

```
{
"scripts": {
  "testScript3": "shx rm -rf ./temp && dotenv cross-var git clone %REPO_PULL_URL% ./temp",
  "testScript5": "cd ./temp && dotenv cross-var git config user.email %REPO_PUSH_AUTHOR%",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
    "dotenv-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "shx": "^0.3.4"
  }
}
```

testScript3 - works fine: it creates temp folder and pulls the repo from the valid url, that was taken from *.env*.

testScript5 - writes `email = %REPO_PUSH_AUTHOR%` to the config, which means the value was not extracted properly.

My latest finding is that *.env* should be in the root, which was probably broken by the *cd* command. It seems I have to use config for that ( e.g. [dotenv is not loading properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767148/dotenv-is-not-loading-properly) ) but I don't really want to move the script to *.js (not yet, at least).

So, the question is: is there a way to pass the config, or should I consider extracting to js? Or any other, better options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up with switching to *.js. I've realized that the case is a bit too specific, the existing libs are not quite fit.

Used *shelljs* and *dotenv* libs to get env vars and manage FS. Works perfectly on both Mac and Windows.

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
require('dotenv').config();

const REPO_PUSH_URL = process.env.REPO_PUSH_URL;
const REPO_PUSH_AUTHOR = process.env.REPO_PUSH_AUTHOR;

shell.cd('./project');

if (shell.exec('git init').code !== 0) {
    shell.echo('Error: Git init failed');
    shell.exit(1);
}
```